# Python encoding issue (ascii > unicode)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, utf-8, python-2.7

I am having a typical utf-8 encoding issue, but so far I haven't been able to resolve it.

```
class StatsTandE(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    conn = rdbms.connect(instance=_INSTANCE_NAME, database='origami')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ui.displayName, ui.title, ui.costCenter FROM views AS v')
    results = [[str(row[0]), str(row[1]), str(row[2])] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    logging.info('results identified as %s', results)

    template_file_name = 'templates/stats_results.html'
    template_values = {
      'results': results,
    }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), template_file_name)
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
    conn.close()
```

The error I am seeing is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Changing `str(row[0])` to `str(row[0]).encode('utf-8')` didn't work...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of python are you using ? Unicode issues are resolved in different way whether you are using python 2.X or python 3.

Comment: If the string is going to contain UTF-8 characters, you should use the `unicode` datatype in Python 2.

Comment: We are using Python 2.7. How would I set the `unicode` datatype?

Comment: what happens if you just remove all `str` calls? General rule for data that represents text: convert from bytes to Unicode as soon as possible on input, use Unicode everywhere inside your program, convert to bytes from Unicode as late as possible on output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `str(row[0])` to `unicode(row[0])`.

Update: As others have stated: you should not even be using `unicode` and `str` unless you need it. Try just `row[0], row[1], row[2]`. When you need to display it, do something like this: `row[0].encode('utf8')`.

Comment: That worked! However, how would I then convert the unicode once more into a string so that it displays nicely on the page? Would I decode it once more?